# Run a monitor at a higher resolution than its native one

Tags: windows-7, resolution

My MacBook Pro has a feature that allows you to run it at a higher resolution than its native one, where it down samples it to match my display. It does this purely to fit more on the screen.

Does Windows 7 have a similar feature? I've even seen it in games on Windows, but I'd like to do it for everything, not just a specific program or game.

My monitors native resolution is 1600x900. I'd like to try to run it at 1920x1080.

Also I have heard in a few places that there is possibly some danger to doing this. What exactly would that danger be?

Comment: I think the danger is related to CRT monitors that could be damaged by running them at higher than their native resolution / refresh rate, I don't think there is a risk with modern displays.

Comment: @stib so no danger for a modern LCD?

Comment: Well, don't sue me if it catches fire, but I'd be very surprised if it did anything worse than just not work at the higher resolution.

Comment: LCDs have a a physical arrangement of pixels, and they are always what display the content.  Down-sampling just displays different content.  You lose detail and fine lines because you can't see more actual detail than the native resolution.  But you won't damage the display.